# How to perform multiple array unnest() in parallel in Presto

Tags: presto

I have the following table in this format

```
create table raw_data (

userid BIGINT,
city  VARCHAR,
campaign ARRAY <
       STRUCT <campaignid BIGINT,
               campaign_start_at TIMESTAMP,
               campaign_ends_at TIMESTAMP,
               parameters ARRAY<
                           STRUCT < goal VARCHAR,
                                    reward VARCHAR
                                  >
               campaignstatus ARRAY
                          STRUCT < seen BOOLEAN ,
                                   seen_at TIMESTAMP
                                   action VARCHAR,
                                   action_at TIMESTAMP
                                  >
                                >
                 >)
```

I want the final result to be like this:

```
userid|city|campaignid|campaign_start_at|campaign_ends_at|goal|reward|seen|seen_at|action|action_at

1 | Athens | 234   | 2019-03-19 12:00 |2019-03-19 14:00| 10| 2.7 | yes |2019-03-19 10:23|null|null
1 | Athens | 234   | 2019-03-19 12:00 |2019-03-19 14:00| 10| 2.7 | yes |2019-03-17 10:23|participate|2019-03-19 11:20
2 | Athens | 234   | 2019-03-19 12:00 |2019-03-19 14:00| 10| 2.7 | yes |2019-03-19 10:23|ignore|2019-03-19 10:10
3 | Athens | 234   | 2019-03-19 12:00 |2019-03-19 14:00| 10| 2.7 | null|null|null|null
3 | Athens | 234   | 2019-03-19 12:00 |2019-03-19 14:00| 10| 2.7 | yes |2019-03-19 12:23|blocked|2019-03-19 12:24
```

In other words, I want to unnest the data and find info on userid level.
I have tried to unnest the table using the following script

```
select * 
FROM raw_data 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(campaign) as t(campaigns)
```

but it returns error: **Table hive.default.campaign does not exist**

My questions are:

Is it possible to unnest multiple arrays in parallel in presto?

- If yes, how do i do that?
- If not, what order should i follow to unnest the columns in the higher level (userid) eg: inside-out or vice versa? An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Table hive.default.campaign does not exist" -- this doesn't sound like a right message, but is there a `campaign` column in `events` table?

Comment: Also, is your intention to produce a cartesian product of `parameters` and `campaignstatus` or "zip" them?

Comment: Hey @PiotrFindeisen! First things first, **events** table is wrong naming- corrected. It should be the table raw_data instead (and yes, `raw_data` has a campaign column)

To your second question, I would like to have a cartesian product of `campaigns`, `parameters` & `campaignstatus`. I want all these three arrays to be linked to the uderid.

eg: userid = 1 has two records of the same campaign id (234), one record was seen from the user but he did no action but when the user saw the campaign for the second time he participated.

I dont know if the above make sense?

Comment: FYI: the returned error was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I found a solution, rather simple but it works.

In order to unnest all the nested arrays you need to work from the outter array towards to the inner array. For this example

- first unnest the `campaign` array  based on userid
- secondly unnest the `campaignstatus` array base on userid and campaignid
- thirdly unnest the `parameters` array. Important note: `parameters` array may be manipulated as an object (not array) as all the data are strings and can be accessed with json functions.

More specifically, the query will be like this:

```
select 
   a.userid
   ,a.city
   ,a.campaignid 
   ,a.campaign_start_at 
   ,a.campaign_ends_at TIMESTAMP
   ,cs.sseen
   ,cs.seen_at
   ,cs.action
   ,cs.action_at
   ,json_array_get(cast(parameters as json),0) goal
   ,json_array_get(cast(parameters as json),1) reward

from (
       select
       userid
      ,city
      ,campaignid 
      ,campaign_start_at 
      ,campaign_ends_at TIMESTAMP

      from raw_data
      cross join unnest(campaign) as c
   ) a

cross join unnest(campaignstatus) as cs
```

However, I would love to read more sophisticated solutions.

Comment: Note: you don't need subquery (`FROM (SELECT ...`), as you can `CROSS JOIN UNNEST (...) CROSS JOIN UNNEST (...)` multiple times.

Comment: Note: you probably want to use `LEFT JOIN UNNEST .. ON true` rather than `CROSS JOIN` -- so that you don't lose rows in case when one of the unnested arrays is empty. (You need a decently recent Presto version for this. If your current version doesn't support `LEFT JOIN UNNEST`, grab Presto 327 from https://prestosql.io/download.html)

Comment: Many thanks @PiotrFindeisen. Will try both suggestion!

Comment: BTW if you have any questions about Presto that do not fit SO formula, I invite you to the [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html)

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for mention it!