# Format unnested field containing date data type in presto

Tags: arrays, json, timestamp, date-format, presto

I have a table in json format with multiple nested arrays.

One of these arrays contains values of date format. **Before unnesting** the (nested) array, date values have this format: **2019-10-05T08:00:00+0000**.

After unnesting the array, the data format is **double** or **integer** like this: **1570262400000**.

How can I transform the double data type into a date format?

Comment: I have found this relevant post here: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/10567

However ,this solution is not applicable to my dataset. The reason why is that the data returned when unnesting is double and not string which is the suitable input for the function `from_iso8601_timestamp` . 
Trying to cast the unnested column as varchar but this returns an error of invalid format: Invalid format: "1.5702372E9" is malformed at ".5702372E9"

Comment: Can you share the SQL you currently use?

Comment: postgresql. Not sure about the version.

Comment: I meant the SQL query text.

Comment: I just unnest the field. No further manipulation and the data returned of the unnested field is the double format described earlier. 

The sql query may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567759/how-to-perform-multiple-array-unnest-in-parallel-in-presto/59570488?noredirect=1#comment105315906_59570488